# incorrect results with gets () due to the stray \n in istream BUT not with scanf() or cin?

Tags: c++, c, scanf, cin, gets

In the program printed below the problem with gets () is that it takes the data for the first time only, and every subsequent call results in a null, due to the stray \n in the istream left while entering the number.

```
main()
{
    char name[20];
    int number;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("enter name");
        gets(s);
        printf("enter phone number");
        cin>>a;
    }
}
```

Now my question is that why isn't the same happening for when I use `scanf()` or `cin` ? I mean whats the difference in the way cin and gets() takes their values which enables cin (and scanf ) to successfully leave that stray `\n` but not `gets()` ?

PS: I know about fgets(), and that gets() is deprecated and its ill-effects, and generally dont use it as well.

Comment: `gets()` is not just deprecated, it's been removed altogether from the latest C standard, because it cannot be used safely (think about what happens if I enter a 30-character string for `name`). *Never* use `gets()`. If you feel the urge to use `gets()`, lie down until the feeling passes. You can use `fgets()` instead -- but then you have to deal with the `\n` that it leaves in the target array.

Comment: haha...but just lying down might not be enough I guess :)

And I knew these things about gets() and fgets(), my question was something else actually. Thanks anyways !

Comment: Understood -- but `gets()` is *such* a bad function that it shouldn't be used even in sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` and `cin >>` both read fields delimeted by whitespace, and ignore leading whitespace.  Now whitepsace is spaces, tabs, AND NEWLINES, so extra newlines in the input doesn't bother them.  More importantly, after reading something, they DO NOT read any of the following whitespace, instead leaving it on the input for the next call to read.

Now with `scanf`, you can tell it explicitly to read (and throw away) as much whitespace as it can by using a space at the end of the format string, but that will work poorly for interactive input, as it will KEEP trying to read until it gets some non-whitepsace.  so if you change the end of your loop to:

```
printf("enter phone number");
scanf("%d ", &a);
```

it will seem to hang after entering the phone number, as its waiting for you to enter some non-whitespace, which will ultimately be read by the next loop iteration as the next name.

You CAN use scanf to do what you want -- read and consume the text following the phone number up to the newline -- but its not pretty:

```
scanf("%d%*[^\n]", &a); scanf("%*1[\n]");
```

You actually need two scanf calls to consume the newline as well as any space or other cruft that might be on the line.

Comment: More accurately, it's the *conversion specifier* that causes `scanf` to skip leading whitespace; you'd have the exact same problem if you used `scanf` with the `%c` conversion specifier.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing line-oriented input with field-oriented input. Functions like `gets()`, `fgets()`, etc read *lines*. They don't care necessarily the contents of the line, but they'll read the whole line (provided there's space for it in some cases).

Field oriented inputs like `cin`'s `>>` operator and `scanf()` don't care about lines, they care about fields. A call like `scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);` doesn't care if they're on the same line or 3 separate lines (or even if you leave blank lines).

These field oriented input functions tend to leave behind newline characters that will confuse line oriented input functions.  In general, you should avoid mixing the two, If you want to do both, it's often useful to read the line then use `sscanf()` or `stringstream` to do field based input from it.  This also makes recovering from bad inputs a bit easier, and you won't have to worry about whether or not there are extra `'\n'` chars waiting for your next input function.

Comment: But even for field oriented input functions like scanf() here for inputting the char[20] only knows to stop at arrival of a newline. Then how come they're not getting distracted by the stray \n ?

Comment: Most conversion specifiers tell `scanf` to skip any *leading* whitespace characters and start conversion at the first non-whitespace character (`%c` is the exception, and would behave exactly like `gets` in your example).  If there are no non-whitespace characters after the leading whitespace, then `scanf` will block until it receives more data from the standard input stream.

Answer (score 0):

`gets()`, unlike `fgets()`, should **replace** a terminating newline with a null character.
This is from `gets()` man page:

> The gets() function shall read bytes from the standard input stream, stdin, into the array pointed to by s, until a  is read or an end-of-file condition is encountered. Any  shall be discarded and a null byte shall be placed immediately after the last byte read into the array."

Though `fgets()` will pass the newline unchanged:

> The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s, until n-1 bytes are read, or a  is read and transferred to s, or an end-of-file condition is encountered. The string is then terminated with a null byte.

So, seems that your implementation is unconforming... Mine works as stated.

Comment: I know about gets() and fgets(). My question's something else !